# Would 'being parented' questions be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have seen some really good advice on this site. Would it be on topic for a child to ask a life-skills question here in order to gain some 'parenting'?

(I'm not a young person myself.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a Stack Exchange rule which excludes the under 13's from having an account, so younger children are excluded from your suggestion, but for the older children I can see no problem in having them ask questions, as long as they remain on topic. They may need to be rephrased (we have had some like that before)

From our [site scope](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> We welcome questions on topics like these:
>
> - matters of upbringing,
> - safety considerations,
> - food and feeding,
> - health and hygiene,
> - development and growth,
> - language development,
> - behavior and social skills,
> - discipline and punishment,
> - childrens'/family games for developmental purposes or parental sanity.
>
> Some subjects might be on-topic here but you can get better response on our sister sites, for instance:
>
> - Scientific questions about child psychology (see the developmental-psychology tag on Cognitive Sciences SE)
> - sports and fitness (see fitness.SE),
> - computer games, educational software, other IT questions (see superuser),
> - family finances (see money.SE).
>
> And some subjects are considered off-topic because they're not directly related to parenting, for instance:
>
> - specific medical issues (we're not doctors!),
> - legal issues (too localized),
> - shopping recommendations (too localized, and not timeless),
> - relationships,
> - sex,
> - generic and universal questions that are lazily worded "... for kids".

Comment: Worth mentioning Law.SE? (I suppose that's actually a question more for that help page than for your post.)