# Are questions about our relations with parents on topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

When is it suitable to ask questions related to our relationship with our parents? Most of the questions I have noticed recently are about how to raise our kids and how to act with them, however this [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/22407/my-parents-are-taking-over-my-life-i-think-im-going-insane) was different, it was about our parents.

I am having some problem with my parents and I am seeing psychologists related to my situation with them. However, there are still many things I would like to understand. Can I ask here?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can ask about issues with your parents. Although it is not specified in our list of [site scope](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/937/9327t), it has been done often, and falls under *matters of upbringing*. For example, see [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/22295/9327) and [this one](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/22407/9327) and their answers.

These types of questions tend to be less well received (the main focus here is how to proceed with parenting), but being confronted with what went wrong is also a valuable learning experience for parents.