# Can children ask questions here? If not where?

Tags: discussion, support, faq

I am an adult.

On a non-Stack-Exchange forum, a child is asking for advice on an interaction with their parents.

I thought to redirect them here.

1. Is there an age limit for participation in Stack Exchange?
2. Would it make sense to redirect a youngster here to get advice from adults?
3. Off-topic but does anyone have other suggestions? Of course online safety is of prime importance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How is this question different from [the one you posted a few years ago](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/936/would-being-parented-questions-be-on-topic-here)? It seems quite duplicate-ish?

Comment: @ Stephie - Thanks for that. I must admit that I had completely forgotten about it. I don't  even remember my motivation for asking back then. The main difference that I can can think of is that today,  I saw an actual call for advice on a language forum. The question was closed, naturally enough, for being off-topic.  I felt a certain responsibility - not to offer any help myself, but at least to consider offering an avenue for finding help.

Answer (score 5):

The rules of participation are very clear where age is concerned:
You must be at least 13 or 16 if you’re in the EU. We moderators do enforce these rules. You can check [this post on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/why-cant-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old-or-if-im-under-16-yea) for more details.

That said, if the child in question is old enough to participate, we do welcome posts by children. There are plenty of examples already on the site. I think redirecting a child (or rather, a teenager) to this community can be a good thing. Note that the usual rules for questions (on topic, not opinion-based etc.) apply and that we expect everyone to honor the Code of Conduct.

Comment: I don't know the age but, at a guess, it's probably a younger teen. I'm reluctant to make any enquiries and I don't intend to offer any advice myself.  I'll think about it and search online for helplines for youngsters. I need to make sure it's a genuine one though.